# enable studio-bot in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm looking to enhance my workflow in Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 stable release build version by utilizing the Studio-bot feature, but I'm unsure of how to enable it. Studio-bot seems like a promising tool for streamlining development tasks, such as automated code reviews, suggestion integrations, and performance optimizations. However, despite browsing through the documentation and exploring various settings within Android Studio, I haven't been able to locate the option to activate Studio-bot. Can anyone provide guidance on where to find and enable Studio-bot within Android Studio? Any tips, instructions, or insights into leveraging this feature effectively would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!